# MySQL Inner Join based query gives duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have written a query using inner join which consist of multiple tables

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       admin_info 
INNER JOIN admin_login 
INNER JOIN gender 
INNER JOIN admin_type 
INNER JOIN area 
INNER JOIN document_type 
INNER JOIN permissions 
ON         admin_login.admin_id=admin_info.admin_id 
AND        admin_type.admin_type_id=admin_info.admin_type_id 
AND        area.area_id=admin_info.area_id 
AND        document_type.document_id=admin_info.document_id 
AND        permissions.permission_id=admin_info.permission_id
```

The above query works but gives multiple results of the same record or duplicate records
Please help me fix the query or provide with an alternative to this query
also please suggest me ways to optimize the query for faster processing??

The above Query

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       admin_info 
INNER JOIN admin_login 
INNER JOIN gender 
INNER JOIN admin_type 
INNER JOIN area 
INNER JOIN document_type 
INNER JOIN permissions 
ON         admin_login.admin_id=admin_info.admin_id 
AND        admin_type.admin_type_id=admin_info.admin_type_id 
AND        area.area_id=admin_info.area_id 
AND        document_type.document_id=admin_info.document_id 
AND        permissions.permission_id=admin_info.permission_id
```

Below Given is the screen shot of the results.

[image]

I want only one record per person and not duplicate records?

Apart from that when i use foreach/while loop the results vary please help?

Comment: Can you share the table structure and expected output?

Comment: there are many tables should i share all the tables ?

Comment: i just need the query to output one record per user i:e no duplicate records !

Comment: What if the child/foreign key tables have multiple records associated with one person?

Comment: Are all the columns shown in result belong to the same table?

Comment: all except one the userid

Comment: show other table datas

Answer (score 0):

**Actually The problem was with gender table which had no reference in the query as soon as i removed the gender table inner join it worked as expected!**

Comment: can you please post `gender` table data and structure?

Comment: Also I can see you are not using `gender` data anywhere in your result, why and where do you needed?